# My included layout doesn't fill the whole space when I set the visibility with View.GONE

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I don't know if it's the right way to do this but I hope you'll be able to help me.

I'm using a ListActivity to display content from RSS feed. While the content is loading I want to display a pending view. I'm using the EndlessAdapter from that website https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless. It provides a way to display a pending view but the first time it loads data it's a tiny row in an empty list so it's not very sexy.

I'm actually trying to fix this up with this method :
A custom layout for my ListActivity where there is a pending view that I can hide or show for the first loading. The XML code of the layout is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"/>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        layout="@layout/loading_anim">
    </include>
</LinearLayout>
```

The first time I load data I set the list visibility to gone with this line :

```
listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It's almost working but the included layout doesn't fill the entire screen and right know I don't know how to fix this in a proper way.

Hope someone will be able to help me, thank's!

**UPDATE :**
I tried to set the contentview with only the loading layout (see XML below) and I got the same result (see http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/loadingwf.png/) :

`this.setContentView(R.layout.loading_anim);`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/loading" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So I'm wondering if maybe it's because of the tabs... Can anybody help me ? Thank's

**UPDATE 2**
I found a solution, it had nothing to do with the neverending adapter. See [The content of my tabs doesn't fill the whole space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140542/the-content-of-my-tabs-doesnt-fill-the-whole-space)

Comment: Use Hierarchy View after calling `setVisibility()` to see where things are going wrong. You might also consider temporarily putting your widgets in the layout vs. using the `<include>` while debugging.

Comment: Hope so you had solved your problem

Comment: Thank's for the answer but it's not working anyway. I put my included layout directly in the main layout but it's the same result. I also used the Hierarchy Viewer and as expected the list is not displayed so normally it doesn't take any space.

Comment: I tried to add a LinearLayout with a height set to wrap_content around my ListView but it's not working either...

Comment: I found a solution, it had nothing to do with the neverending adapter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140542/the-content-of-my-tabs-doesnt-fill-the-whole-space

Answer (score 1):

In your ListView, try this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"/>
```

What I did was set layout_height to wrap_content. Should fill your entire screen now.

Comment: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` usually does not work well on `ListView`, as the height is variable.